# UnityException: GetAssetPath can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность

Ошибка:

```
UnityException: GetAssetPath can only be called from the main thread.
    Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
```

Я в потоке обрабатываю размещение на Террайн объектов и когда начинаю вызывать методы которые находятся не в классе Worker начинаются проблемы:

> может быть вызван только из основного потока.

Как с этим бороться?

Мой код:

```
        private Worker _worker;
        public static bool pressedbool = false;
        private Thread _thread;
        private UnityEngine.Object _locker;
        public static int _progress;
...
    void DrawFooter()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(FooterSection);
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        if (!pressedbool)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Выберите json");
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            stringTextFieldURLjsonfile = GUILayout.TextField(stringTextFieldURLjsonfile);
            if (GUILayout.Button("Обзор...", GUILayout.Width(100)))
            {
                stringTextFieldURLjsonfile = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Выбрать json", "", "json");
            }
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Старт"))
            {

                pressedbool = true;
                _worker = new Worker();
                _worker.ProcessChanged += worker_ProcessChanged;
                _worker.WorkCompleted += worker_WorkCompleted;

                _worker.myList = myList;
                _worker.count_list_index = count_list_index;
                _worker.GamObjArrayTexture = GamObjArrayTexture;
                _worker.TerrainList = TerrainList;
                _worker.brushsize = brushsize;

                Worker._cancelled = false;

                // _thread = new Thread(_worker.ProcessJSONPlaceONmapTextures);
                _thread = new Thread(() => _worker.ProcessJSONPlaceONmapTextures("", null));
                // if (count_list_index >= 0)
                // {
                //     if (myList[count_list_index].geometry_type == 0)
                //     {
                //         ProcessJSONPlaceONmapTextures();
                //     }
                //     else if (myList[count_list_index].geometry_type == 1)
                //     {
                //         // ProcessJSONPlaceONmap();
                //     }
                // }

                _locker = new UnityEngine.Object();
                _progress = 0;
                _thread.Start();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Стоп"))
            {
                pressedbool = false;
                Worker.Cancel();
            }

            while (jobs.Count > 0)
                jobs.Dequeue().Invoke();

            EditorGUI.ProgressBar(new Rect(3, 45, FooterSection.width - 6, 20), _progress / 100.0f, "progress: " + _progress + "%");
        }
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

Класс в котором обрабатывается расчёты:

```
   public class Worker
    {
        public static bool _cancelled = false;
        public List<mapObject> myList = null;
        public int count_list_index = -3;
        public Texture2D[] GamObjArrayTexture = null;
        public Terrain[] TerrainList = new Terrain[0];
        public float brushsize = 3;
        public static void Cancel()
        {
            _cancelled = true;
        }
        public event Action<int> ProcessChanged;
        public event Action<bool> WorkCompleted;

        public void ProcessJSONPlaceONmapTextures(string tempStringTextFieldURLjsonfile = "", List<Terrain> templstTerrain = null)
        {
         ...
         marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(0);
         List<string> listStringUrlTexture = getListStringUrlTexture();
         marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(100);
         ...
        }

        public List<string> getListStringUrlTexture()
        {
            List<string> listStringUrlTexture = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < GamObjArrayTexture.Length; i++)
            {
                if (GamObjArrayTexture[i] != null)
                {

                    string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[i]); //ошибка
                    listStringUrlTexture.Add(path);
                }
            }
            return (listStringUrlTexture.Count > 0) ? listStringUrlTexture : null;
        }
}
```

[Нашёл ответ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916533/setactive-can-only-be-called-from-the-main-thread) Но не до конца понял как это работает , может кто то сможет объяснить как поступать в моём случае?

Comment: В юнити пошли по принципу наименьшего сопротивления и просто запретили любому коду с других потоков что-то трогать в основном потоке (и это хорошо). Поэтому проще просто написать свой/взять чужой диспетчер, который будет делегировать вызовы в основной поток.

Comment: В ответе по ссылке можно найти уже полностью реализованный диспетчер, не совсем понимаю, в чем вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker У меня не получается сделать как в ответе. Можно , если есть время , написать как это будет выглядеть для моего случая?

Comment: Это уж тогда попозже сегодня. Почему у вас `_cancelled` общий для всех рабочих потоков кстати?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  Пока это пилотный вариант . Позже его видоизменю, тем более как дочитаю про потоки. Я с потоками имел дело только в C++

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да и думаю общий _cancelled позволить прервать все потоки . Или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: А зачем вам прерывать все потоки разом? А что, если вы захотите прервать только 1 поток? Это просто в целом странная задумка немного.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102251/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ я опубликовал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1060765/178835). В краце класс [Dispatcher](http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/) помогает избежать ошибок типа :

```
UnityException: GetAssetPath can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в корутинах, они создают новые `thread`.

`GetAssetPath` это просто `string`. Её можно определить заранее и записать куда-нибудь, что-бы потом обращаться к ней, а не методу.

Comment: А если не определять за ранее, как можно изменить код чтоб он работал ?

Comment: "GetAssetPath can **ONLY** be called from the **MAIN thread**". Либо заранее, либо отправить в main thread, но я тут я не советчик

Comment: Вроде тебе всего-лишь нужно в `DrawFooter` добавить `_worker.listStringUrlTexture = ...;`. Если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Но помимо этого вызова мне надо будет делать и другие . Я хочу научиться делать как в ответе , ссылку на который я в вопросе опубликовал