# Функция в Unity наподобие SetInterval из JavaScript

Tags: c#, unity3d, время

Нужно вызывать функцию каждый определённый n-ый промежуток времени.

Например:  если `n == 0.5`, то вызывается func1() каждые 0.5с (пол секунды).

Как это сделать легко и просто? Например в JS есть функция `SetInterval`, Есть ли в C# Unity что-то наподобие?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант через `Time.deltaTime`.

```
float DelayTimer = 0;
float Delay = 0.5f;

void Update () {
     DelayTimer += Time.deltaTime;
     if (DelayTimer >= Delay) {
         DelayTimer -= Delay;
         GetOverHere();
     }
}
```

Comment: Корутины не используют потоки, они запускаются в мейн треде юнити.

Comment: Так разве корутина не причина ошибки `only main thread` тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059354/unityexception-getassetpath-can-only-be-called-from-the-main-thread Он ведь вроде изначально одной только корутиной без потока делал? Иди я ошибся

Comment: Так там же нет корутин, там создаются отдельные потоки. Корутины - это лишь имитация потоков, на самом деле юнити с помощью yield инструкций просто откладывает выполнение кода в корутинах на потом, многопоточности там нет)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да, сам почитал. Спасибо буду знать) Инет полнится большими статьями на эту тему)

Answer (score 1):

В Unity есть [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Создайте свой метод:

```
private IEnumerator Func1() {
    // бесконечный цикл
    for (;;) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        // этот код будет выполняться каждые полсекунды

        // а здесь какое-то условие для выхода из цикла
    }
}
```

И запустите в вашем [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) скрипте с помощью `StartCoroutine`:

```
StartCoroutine(Func1());
```

`Func1` будет выполняться каждые полсекунды.